# JS callback using map() with a function that has one additional parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, parameters, callback

I'm trying to find a way to use JS's `Array.prototype.map()` functionality with a function that has one additional parameter more (if possible at all, and I'd like to *avoid* having to rewrite built-in `Array.prototype.map()`).
This documentation is very good, but does not cover the "one-or-more-additional-parameter" case:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
function doOpSingle(elem)
{
 // do something with one array element
}

var A = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var x = A.map(doOpSingle); // this will execute doOpSingle() on each array element
```

So far, so good.
But what if the function in question has **two** parameters, like e. g. a flag you might want to OR to it (think of bit masks)

```
function doOpSingle2(arrelem,flag)
{
 // do something with one array element
}

var A = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var theFlag = util.getMask(); // call external function
var y = A.map(doOpSingle2(theFlag)); // this does not work!
```

Any solutions should do **without** `for` loops, of course, because that's why we have `map()`, to make our code cleaner w/getting rid of these!

Answer (score 20):

Use an anonymous function:

```
A.map(function(a) {return doOpSingle2(a,theFlag);});
```

Comment: +1, realised after posting my answer :)

Comment: TY! This will most likely be the only way to cover this task (apart from bind()). Thanks to the other answerers as well.

Answer (score 14):

`A.map(doOpSingle2.bind(null, theFlag))`

`theFlag` will be first argument though:

`function doOpSingle2( flag, elem ) { ... }`

Comment: Love this bind() technique, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function.

```
var y = A.map(function(x){doOpSingle2(x,theFlag);});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Nevermind, you don't really need Closure for this. See Esailija's answer.

There is another option, if you happen to be using the [Closure library](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/). First you have to rewrite doOpSingle2 so that the flag is first:

```
function doOpSingle2(flag, arrelem)
{
 // do something with one array element
}
```

then you can do

```
var y = A.map(goog.partial(doOpSingle2, theFlag));
```

goog.partial *partially applies* the function, so `goog.partial(doOpSingle2, theFlag)` is equivalent to this function:

```
function(arrElem) {
  return doOpSingle2(theFlag, arrElem);
}
```

In this particular case, I probably wouldn't recommend this approach, but there might be similar situations where it works well.

Comment: javascript can already do currying with `.bind` though

Comment: THIS is the very problem. It would just be overkill to use an external library for this little problem. But still, thanks anyway for this approach. In a _real_ big project, I might need this technique someday. ;)

Comment: That's why I said "if you happen to be using Closure" instead of "you should drop everything right now and start using Closure" the way [some people do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/65977) ;).