# Can we slice string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like below

```
array_object = [video1.mp4 , video2.mp4 , video3.mp4];
```

I like to remove the .mp4 from the array so i used

```
array = array_object.slice(0,-4);
```

but it not working cause the string is in array.
are there anyway to delete the .mp4 even it inside the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript map method on array of string elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925609/javascript-map-method-on-array-of-string-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over the items. This can be done with an array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const array_object = ['video1.mp4', 'video2.mp4', 'video3.mp4'];

const new_array = array_object.map(item => item.slice(0, -4));

console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

As get of my lawn said use `array.map`. Array.map gets as an argument a callback function which gets executed on every element of the array. Then a new array is returned. For example:

```js
const array_object = ['video1.mp4', 'video2.mp4', 'video3.mp4'];

const new_array = array_object.map(item => item.slice(0, -4));

console.log(array_object === new_array); // logs false a new array is returned;
```

The function which is passed in map gets every array index as an argument:

```
item => item.slice(0, -4)
```

Then on every element the function is performed and put in the index of the new array.