# Accept both stringified and normal array

Tags: typescript

I am working with stenciljs using typescript, my component can be used anywhere and user can send data in stringified array or normal array for example as below

```
<my-component data ="JSON.stringify([1,3,4]") />
```

and user can also pass normal array well like below:

```
  <my-component data=[1,4,5] />
```

so in My stencil component i have below stuff.

```
       export class Charts {
          @Prop() data: string;
          @Prop() chartTitle: string;
          @State() parsedData= [];
        
          componentWillLoad() {
            try {
              this.parsedData = JSON.parse(this.data);
            } catch (error) {
              this.parsedData = this.data || [];  // here it gives me error Type 'string | undefined[]' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'
            }
          }

}
```

I have provided error in comments, please refer above code, if I make `@State:parsedData:any=[];` this works but I would like not to use any here, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TypeScript Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html)

```
@State() parsedData: string | [] = [];
```

Comment: but this says :Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | []'.Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'. in render functio

Comment: any help here, like I always want to map array elements

Comment: You cann't use `map` on string. [Try this solution instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54092488/9611676)